# IIS Express response is 502 Bad Gateway but can browse in IE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-7, iis-express

I'm getting a 502 error back from IIS Express when I try to do a POST some XML to the localhost:port URL, but I can happily browse to the site ... http://localhost:2656/PoxService/help ... and see the generated help page

And it works fine as an IIS site, it's the hosting in IIS Express that is failing   :-(

This is NET 4 POX project, created using the "WCF REST Service Application" template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS Express runs under current logged on user identity whereas IIS worker process runs under app pool identity (which is a member of  IIS_IUSRS group). Since it is working in IIS and not working in IIS Express, can you add current logged on user to IIS_IUSRS group and check if this works?